# Specify precompiled headers directory with xctool

Tags: ios, cocoapods, travis-ci, xctool

I have an Xcode workspace with CocoaPods that I'm trying to build using `xctool` on travis. Here's the command that I'm using to do the build:

```
xctool -workspace MyApp.xcworkspace -scheme MyApp -sdk iphoneos -configuration Release SYMROOT=$PWD/build OBJROOT=$PWD/build ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO
```

This successfully builds the static libraries for each CocoaPod and the final app and dSYM into the `$PWD/build` directory, but the precompiled headers are still placed in `DerivedData`. I need them to be built into the `$PWD/build` directory for caching. Is there any way to specify where the precompiled headers are built to?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. I needed to add `SHARED_PRECOMPS_DIR=$PWD/build` onto the `xctool` command.